# There are 10 men and 10 women. How many ways are there to arrange these 20 people at a round table with 25 seats?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

How many ways are there to arrange 20 people at a round table with 25 seats? (Rotations are considered the same arrangement.)

Is it just a simple permutation problem of 25P10 = 25!/15! or does the fact that it's a circle change things? Is it instead (25-1)!/5!

Comment: What does the fact that $10$ are men and $10$ are women have to do with the problem?  How is it different from just seating $20$ people?

Comment: @saulspatz it doesn't. that part can be disregarded

Comment: You have not accounted for the fact that rotations are considered to be equivalent or the fact that empty seats are considered to be indistinguishable.

Comment: Hint: There are $5$ places which are not being used. Think about the ways that these $5$ empty seats can be placed around the table. For example, there could be $4$ empty seats in a row, and another $1$ empty seat by itself.

Comment: If all the people are distinguishable, then it is just $(25!/5!)/25 = 24!/5!$.  If men are indistinguishable from each other, and women are indistinguishable from each other (e.g., you are placing gendered seatings), then it's more complicated, since you have to consider symmetries.  I *think* you're looking for the number of [necklaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necklace_(combinatorics)) with 10 beads of one color, 10 beads of a second color, and 5 beads of a third color, but I haven't thought about it carefully yet.  (Assuming I've understood the problem correctly.)

Comment: $\frac{{}_{25} P_{20}}{25}$